# PrimeFaces doesn't update inputtext of formA using values of formB

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to update the inputtext with id **callef** in the form **formUsuario** and its bean is **psFacNomVialidad** that also is in *MigracionController* however, I'm trying to make that update using the value inputted in my inputtext with id **calle** this inputtex is in another form (**dlgFormVerif**) and has its own bean (**psNomVialidad**), the value of **psFactNomVialidad** is the same as **psNomVialidad** because a method is triggered after the dialog is closed that assigns values and also updates **formUsuario** but for some reason is not working, what am I missing?.

> MigracionController.java

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MigracionController extends AbstractBaseController {
    @Getter @Setter
    private String psNomVialidad;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String psFacNomVialidad;
    ...
    public void verificarDatosFacturacion() {
        ...
        psFacNomVialidad = psNomVialidad;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

> migracion5.xhtml

```html
<h:form role="form" id="formUsuario" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
    <p:panel id="DomFacturacion" class="panel" visible="#{(migracionController.pbDesDatoFacturacion)}">
        ...
            <p:inputText id="callef" class="inputTextForm" value="#{migracionController.psFacNomVialidad}"
                        required="true" rendered="#{(migracionController.pbDesDatoFacturacion)}"/>
        ...
    </p:panel>
    ...
<h:form>

.
.
.

<p:commandButton value="VERIFY INFO" id="showDlgVerif" class="btn" rendered="true" oncomplete="PF('dlgVerif').show();"/>

.
.
.

<p:dialog id="dlgVerif" header="Verify info" class="modal" widgetVar="dlgVerif" modal="true"
              resizable="false" closable="true">
    <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{migracionController.verificarDatosFacturacion()}" update=":formUsuario:DomFacturacion"/>
    <h:form id="dlgFormVerif" rendered="true">
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" id="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        <p:panel styleClass="panel" rendered="true">
            ...
            <p:inputText styleClass="inputTextForm" id="calle"
                        value="#{migracionController.psNomVialidad}"
                        required="#{!migracionController.pbClteExistente}">
                <p:ajax event="change" update=":formUsuario:callef"/>
            </p:inputText>
            ...
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
    <p:commandButton styleClass="btnAzul" value="CLOSE" oncomplete="PF('dlgVerif').hide();"/>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Why the `p:commandButton`  is outside the form? I mean, when do you need to process the input text in the dialog?

Comment: `p:commandButton` is just to close the dialog and the form is process in this ajax
`<p:ajax event="close" listener="#{migracionController.verificarDatosFacturacion()}" update=":formUsuario:DomFacturacion"/>`
The values are assigned and then an update should happen but it doesn't

Comment: But you're not processing the inputText there, hence the server always sees the old value. I would change like this `<p:ajax event="change" update=":formUsuario:callef" process="@this"/>` or process that item/form on close, or redesign the logic for a more linear listener/process/update.

Comment: You're almost right, I had to switch your proposal I mean like this
`<p:ajax event="change" process=":formUsuario:callef" update="calle"/>`
Thank you so much for that clue

Comment: Oh it was the opposite of what I understand. Make it as an answer so you can mark your question as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was updating my items in the front but I wasn't processing them so as WoAiNii suggested in comments I added `process` attribute for `p:ajax` tag and changed the values to achieve what I wanted.
Here is the result

```html
<h:form role="form" id="formUsuario" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
    <p:panel id="DomFacturacion" class="panel" visible="#{(migracionController.pbDesDatoFacturacion)}">
        ...
            <p:inputText id="callef" class="inputTextForm" value="#{migracionController.psFacNomVialidad}"
                        required="true" rendered="#{(migracionController.pbDesDatoFacturacion)}"/>
        ...
    </p:panel>
    ...
<h:form>

.
.
.

<p:commandButton value="VERIFY INFO" id="showDlgVerif" class="btn" rendered="true" oncomplete="PF('dlgVerif').show();"/>

.
.
.

<p:dialog id="dlgVerif" header="Verify info" class="modal" widgetVar="dlgVerif" modal="true"
              resizable="false" closable="true">
    <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{migracionController.verificarDatosFacturacion()}" update=":formUsuario:DomFacturacion"/>
    <h:form id="dlgFormVerif" rendered="true">
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" id="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        <p:panel styleClass="panel" rendered="true">
            ...
            <p:inputText styleClass="inputTextForm" id="calle"
                        value="#{migracionController.psNomVialidad}"
                        required="#{!migracionController.pbClteExistente}">
                <!-- the changes are on the below line -->
                <p:ajax event="change" process=":formUsuario:callef" update="calle"/>
            </p:inputText>
            ...
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
    <p:commandButton styleClass="btnAzul" value="CLOSE" oncomplete="PF('dlgVerif').hide();"/>
</p:dialog>
```